# How do style selectors work in Avalonia?

Tags: xaml, avaloniaui

Selectors look very similar to CSS. What selectors are available in Avalonia? What is the meaning of this selector for example:

```
<Style Selector="ListBoxItem:selected /template/ ContentPresenter">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffff" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, selectors are very similar to CSS. Currently (at 0.5.0 alpha) [the following selectors are available](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/df1aed438d61fdffcb905a76857288c4e1cfb22e/src/Avalonia.Styling/Styling/Selectors.cs). I'm explaining these selectors by example, as otherwise it gets hard to understand:

- `Button`: This selects a control by type, so if you write a selector `Button` then it will match the `Avalonia.Controls.Button` class. It *won't* match derived types [1]
- `:is(Button)`: This is very similar to `Class` except it also matches derived types
- `Button TextBlock`: When two selectors are separated by a space, then the selector will match descendants, so in this case the selector will match any `TextBlock` that is a logical descendant of `Button`
- `Button > TextBlock`: When two selectors are separated by a `>`, then the selector will match children, so in this case the selector will match any `TextBlock` that is a direct logical child of `Button`
- `Button#MyButton` this will match any `Button` with the `Name` of `MyButton`
- `Button.MyClass` this will match any `Button` with the string `MyClass` as an entry in its `Classes`
- `Button:disabled` this will match any `Button` with the [`:disabled` pseudo-class](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/docs/spec/styles.md#pseudoclasses)
- `Button[IsDefault=true]`: this will match any `Button` which has an `IsDefault` property of `true`
- `Button /template/ ContentPresenter` this matches a `ContentPresenter` in the control template of a `Button` [2]

[1]: Note the type of an object is actually determined by looking at its [`IStyleable.StyleKey`](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/df1aed438d61fdffcb905a76857288c4e1cfb22e/src/Avalonia.Styling/Styling/IStyleable.cs#L27) property, so if you do want your control which inherits from `Button` to be styled as a `Button`, then you can implement the `IStyleable.StyleKey` on your class to return `typeof(Button)`.

[2]: This is similar to the (now deprecated) `/deep/` operator in CSS; CSS shadow DOM is a very similar concept to control templates.